# Elastic Beanstalk "error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'node'."

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to deploy an app to elastic beanstalk's NodeJs Platform (10.15.3) but as it builds (the Node commmand is `npm start --production`) I'm seeing the following errors in logs:

```
npm run build
app@1.0.0 build /var/app/current
tsc -p .
error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'node'.
```

My package.json is the following (it includes @type/node:10.14):

```
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "main": "dist/app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc -p .",
    "prestart": "npm run build",
    "watch": "tsc -w -p .",
    "start": "node .",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/morgan": "^1.7.35",
    "@types/node": "^10.14",
    "aws-sdk": "^2.411.0",
    ...
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/express": "^4.16.1"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add types to your `tsconfig.json`

```
 {
   "compilerOptions": {
      "target": "es6",
      "module": "commonjs",
      "outDir": "dist-api",
      "sourceMap": true,
      "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
      "experimentalDecorators": true,
      "types": ["node"]
   },
   "include": [
      "src/**/*.ts"
   ],
   "exclude": [
      "node_modules"
   ]
}
```